# Which kind of firestore queries require indexes?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Was a bit confused because usually the first time I run a Firestore query with a condition I'm usually required to add an index for the field I'm adding a condition for but this time it didn't, its not really an issue but what am I not understanding about how Firestore queries/indexing works?

```
  const q = query(
    collection(db, 'activityDetails'),
    where('activityId', '==', activityId),
  );
```

I'd assume that since activityId isn't the automatic primary index I'd be required to add it as an index and Firestore usually spits out a link for you to create the index?

Comment: [You might find this documentation useful](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/index-overview#single-field-indexes). Firestore will automatically create single-field indexes for you. It's only composite indexes where you need to create them yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're calling `.where('activityId', '==', activityId)` without adding any kind of order, then there is no need to explicitly create an index. The indexes required for the most basic queries like this one, are automatically created for you. Please see below the docs:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing